# "Login failed for user" when accessing an SSRS report on the Report Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, authentication, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have started migrating the SSRS reports that read our CRM’s database. The main facts are:

- The origin environment is Windows Server 2003 with SQL Server 2005.
- The new environment is Windows Server 2008 R2 with SQL Server 2008 R2
  SP2
- There have been a few changes in our CRM (actually: it's a new software), therefore there has been an
  evolution in the database schema.

What I have been doing:

- Copied a report’s RDL file from the origin environment to the new
  environment
- In a SSRS project (in Visual Studio 2008): used the “add an existing item” to add the RDL to the project
- Edited the report’s data source to use the current shared data source
- Edited the report’s datasets to take the database schema changes into account
- Previewed the report : it runs correctly

However, when I upload the report onto the Report Server and try to access the report from there, I get the following error message:

```
Error occurred during report processing (rsProcessingAborted) 
    Cannot create a connection to data source '[name of data source]'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection) 
        Login failed for user '[username]'.
```

Strangely enough a new reporting (i.e. created on the new environment), using the same shared data source that uses the same user, works fine both in Visual Studio and on the Report Server.

Did I miss something in the migration of the reporting ? I have not been able to find out..

Comment: Can you delete all the reports and datasources off the server and redeploy them? Keep in mind, datasources are by default not overwritten in SSRS when deploying, so if you deployed the old shared datasources before changing them to point to the new SQL instance, changes might not have been deployed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip; it wasn't relevant in my case, but it definitely is a useful information :) The problem was on the development server, there seemed to be a versioning problem there.. Now it's sorted. The question is solved as far as I am concerned.